# Is there a better way to move files and directory up a folder?

Tags: c#

as per title, is there a better way to move all the files and directories up a folder?

This is my code now:

```cs
private static void MoveEverythingUpAFolder(string sourceDir)
{
    foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
    {
        Directory.Move(item, Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(item), "..", Path.GetFileName(item)));
    }

    foreach (var item in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir))
    {
        Directory.Move(item, Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(item).FullName, "..", new DirectoryInfo(item).Name));
    }

    Directory.Delete(sourceDir);
}
```

If I only use `Directory.Move(source, dest)` I get an exception saying that the destination directory already exists...

Comment: Move it to a random name, after move rename it to original name?

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if you have a directory inside your source directory, that matches the source directory name.

For example, you're trying to move `c:\foo\bar\*.*` to `c:\foo`.

However, a directory exists named `c:\foo\bar\bar`.

`foo/bar/bar` cannot be moved to `foo` and become `foo/bar`, because `foo/bar` exists, just like the errors says.

You would be FUBAR. Or perhaps experience an exception.

You could rename the source directory first to something NOT duplicated within that directory, perform your move operations, and then remove the directory.

Comment: There may be other things that can cause the error you're having ... but I've run into this scenario once or twice in the past ...

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether certain things are known constraints or not.

The documentation for the [`Directory.Move(string, string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.move?view=net-7.0) method states:

> This method creates a new directory with the name specified by destDirName and moves the contents of sourceDirName, including files and directories, to the newly created destination directory. It then deletes the sourceDirName directory.
>
> If you try to move a directory to a directory that already exists, an IOException will occur.

If you have a directory structure like the following, attempting to move `a\b\c` to `a\b` will fail with an error because `b` exists.

**`b` will only contain `c` - before changes**

```
 a───b───c─┬─d
           │
           └─f
```

But if you know that directory `b` will only ever contain directory `c` then you can

1. move `a\b\c` to `a\c-temp`
2. delete `b` (which should now be empty)
3. rename `c-temp` to `b`

**after**

```
 a───b─┬─d
       │
       └─f
```

If directory `b` may contain other folders and files as in the following, then finding and moving the individual folders and files may be the best.

**`b` may contain other files/folders - before changes**

```
 a───b─┬─c─┬─d
       │   │
       └─e └─f
```

1. move folders and files in `c` to `b` (be aware there could be name collisions with files/folders already present in `b`)
2. delete `c` (which should now be empty)

**after**

```
 a───b─┐
       │
       ├─e
       │
       ├─d
       │
       └─f
```

Comment: If the directories are actually named like a/b/c/d, this will not fail with the OP's code. I tried it.

Comment: The OP stated that `Directory.Move("a\b\c", "a\b")` fails and that is expected because `"a\b"` exists. The OP's code for moving the files/folders within "a\b\c" works fine and is the second scenario in my answer.  The question wasn't "does this code work?" The question was "is there a better approach?" And the answer is "maybe".

Comment: There is no renaming going on in the OP's snippet, though ... He's not renaming "c" to "b" when he moves it to "a". "a/b/c" should become "a/c" (with "a/b" removed) is how I read it (in his *code*, not the text of his question).

Comment: I don't see his code working like that. The `sourceDir` is "a/b/c". Calling `Directory.GetDirectories("a/b/c")` returns directories "d" and "f" which are moved to "b". Finally, "c" is removed.

Comment: It may make sense to change the code to use `DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories()` in place of `Directory.GetDirectories()`. The body of the `foreach` loop would change to something like `item.MoveTo(Path.Combine(item.Parent.FullName, "..", item.Name));`

Comment: Why would moving d or f to a conflict with b?

Comment: Do you mean to ask "why would moving d or f to b have a conflict?" If b is guaranteed to be empty there will be no conflicts. If b has content there could already be a directory named d or f. For example, if the 'move files and folders up a directory' operation is repeated it will fail.